# Volver texto al original con Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, div

estoy tratando de hacer un sitio en cual mediante un simple click el cliente pueda cambiar el idioma del algunos textos.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#miboton").click(function(){
        $("#micapa").html("Nuevo texto para cambiar");
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="micapa">Texto</div>
<a href="#" id="miboton">Cambiar el contenido</a>
```

Lo que quiero hacer y es que tambien le de la opsion de volver al texto original, se supone que va a cambiar el idioma, pero no puedo hacer que vuelva idioma original. Espero me ayuden y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** Almacenando el texto original (si son muchos es medio locura)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var almacenamientoTemporal = $("#micapa").html();
  $("#miboton").click(function(){
    $("#micapa").html("Nuevo texto para cambiar");
  });
  $("#miotroboton").click(function(){
    $("#micapa").html(almacenamientoTemporal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="micapa">Texto</div>

<a href="#" id="miboton">Cambiar el contenido</a><br />
<a href="#" id="miotroboton">Restaurar el contenido</a>
```

**2** usando array de traducciones

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrayTextos = 
    {1:{'es':'Texto uno en español', 'en':'Text one in Englisch'},
     2:{'es':'Texto dos en español', 'en':'Text two in Englisch'}};
  $(".cambia").click(function(){
   var lang = $(this).data("lang");
   
   $(".texto").each(function(){
     var textoID = $(this).data("id");
     $(this).html(arrayTextos[textoID][lang]);
     });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-id="1" class="texto">Texto 1 en Español (por omisión)</div>
<div data-id="2" class="texto">Texto 2 en Español (por omisión)</div>

<a href="#" class="cambia" data-lang="es">Cambiar el contenido a Español</a><br />
 <a href="#" class="cambia" data-lang="en">Change content to English</a><br />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alo Malbarez....